# Breakpoints not getting hit in Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: debugging, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms add, and I don't know if yesterdays update on  Visual Studio 2019(**16.5.1**) was the reason but when i'm in the debug mode connect with my device on Android Project breakpoints don't hit. The interesting part is my app is working OK. I login in my app , a have responses from my Api but the breakpoints not hit. Did anyone have same problem ? I looks like something is changed in my project. 
**P.S** I made new Xamarin.Forms blank project the breakpoints are heated. Please someone for solution?

Comment: You said that you create new blank Xamarin.forms, and breakpoint get hit successfully, so I guess that your Visual studio have no problem. Please try to close your project and delete obj and bin, than reopen and run your project again firstly.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT i tried that.. I don\t know how this happen . Every other solution i got  breakpoints are hit its okey. Just solution i have worked that time.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT do you have any other suggestions to do? Probably something is missing in the project or i don't know or something need to change? I have big project i don't want to write it from the start

Comment: Please check whether there is some symbols in your project path, for example,path **"D:\C# (+ JS)\demo3\demo3\demo3\bin\Debug"**", the **"("** , **"#"**  and **")"** symbols may cause this trouble.

Comment: I had the same problem with xamarin ios. I found the solution was to smash up my iPhone into little pieces, curse the grave of Jobs and urinate all over my Mac. After this everything seemed to be fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After days of exploring i finally found out that i unchecked Use Shared Runtime.

[image]

Thank you all for your suggestions , i will make post active, because there are other solution's in the comments that might help someone, because this issue dependence of lot of factors.

Comment: You saved me haha. I don't know how or when I unchecked it but had it not been for you it would have been the last place I looked.

Comment: For me it was `PlatformTarget` property set to wrong config, not matching sln config. Cheers!

Comment: Why is the Shared Runtime needed in order for breakpoints to be hit?

Comment: For me selecting fast deployment worked

Comment: For me setting `Link SDKs` to `none` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

there was a flag in android manifest.xml file which says android:debuggable = false

I made that as true and it worked
android:debuggable = true

hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the entire solution worked fine. Visual Studio jumps over the breakpoints because symbols do not align between the Solution and Code. Any alteration of the project results in a rebuild, so instead of playing around with the setting, try and rebuild first and see if that works.