# When debugging in Xamarin, it does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing an app using a combination of Visual Studio 2022 Community, Xamarin.Forms and Android.
In debug mode, I am placing breakpoints, but they do not stop.
Is there something I need to configure?

Start Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 and Windows 11.
Create a Xamarin.Forms application.
Launch debugging.

This project was created in Visual Studio 2019.
Visual Studio 2019 can stop at breakpoints when debugging.
There was no "Use Shared Runtime" item in the Android Options in Visual Studio 2022 Communitey.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you app enters the part of the code where your breakpoint is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breakpoints not getting hit in Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin.Forms project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847928/breakpoints-not-getting-hit-in-visual-studio-2019-xamarin-forms-project)

Comment: Thanks Josip! I sure.

Comment: Hi Larry! Thanks for your comment. I compared and found no "Use Shared Runtime" item in the Android Options of Visual Studio 2022 Communitey. I have added a capture image.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can check the official document about the issue.

Official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/troubleshooting-breakpoints?view=vs-2022

And then, if the issue is still here, you can try to enable the `Use Fast Deployment`. If you need more information, please check the following links:

Similar issue on the Github: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6480

Similar issue in the Visual Studio Community:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Breakpoint-not-hit-debugging-Xamarin-And/1561025

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
(1) There is no mention of Xamarin in the official documentation.

Comment: (2) If I enable Use Fast Deployment, I cannot build.

The error is as follows

Severity Level Code Description Project File Line Suppression Status
Error XA0136: The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: package has corrupt installation: com.companyname.re2022
'.
The current installation of the package in corrupt. 
If that does not work you can disable Fast Deployment.
Fast Deployment can be disabled in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk'. MSBuild property to 'true'.    0

Comment: (3) I unchecked HotRelooad for Xamarin.Forms in Tools-Options, but it does not stop at breakpoints.

Comment: Have you tried to add `<AndroidUseAssemblyStore>false</AndroidUseAssemblyStore>` into the .Android.csproj or change $(DebugType) to portable?@kaoruarcadia

Comment: Thanks comment. I added into Android.csproj. But it does not stop at breakpoints.

Comment: And now can you enable Use Fast Deployment with the change above and the error disappear?@kaoruarcadia

Comment: Thanks Liyun. I add into Android.csproj and Use Fast Deployment with the change, error appear and could not build. Error is this.  XA0136: The 'run-as' command failed with 'run-as: package has corrupt installation: com.re2022'.The currently installation of the package in corrupt. Please manually uninstall the package from all the users on device and try again. If that does not work you can disable Fast Deployment.
Fast Deployment can be disabled in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true'

Comment: Where can I change $(DebugType) to portable?

Comment: I found DebugType at Android.csproj. Debug type is already set to portable.

Comment: Did you try to debug on another device or on a simulator? @kaoruarcadia

Comment: I tryed (1)Windows 10+Visual Studio 2019 Community+Android [success] (2)Windows10+Visual Studio 2022+Android [fail(not stop at breakpoint)].  (3)Windows11+Visual Studio 2022+Android [fail(not stop at breakpoint)]. I have only one Android device.

Comment: Have you tried uninstall the apk on the device after enable fast-deployment?@kaoruarcadia

Comment: And you can try to debug on a simulator, if success means that it is a special bug for this device on the visual studio 2022.@kaoruarcadia

Comment: Thanks omment. I tried uninstall the apk on the device, and enable fast-deployment. But it can't build. the Error is XA0136.

Comment: This may be a new bug for Visual Studio 2022 Community, you can report it according to the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).@kaoruarcadia

Comment: OK I report. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/When-debugging-in-Xamarin-it-does-not-s/10001823?entry=problem

Answer (score -1):

"Use Fast Deployment" helps

[image]